# Drupal and OKTA integration

Tags: drupal, okta

I am integrating Drupal and OKTA. When I try to access my website I am being redirected to Okta for login. But after successful authentication I am not being redirected back to my website.

I am following a SP initiated workflow. My log message in OKTA is as follows.

[image]

Is there a way I can have more debugging information from OKTA to figure out what is going on and what setting is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suspicion is that the target resource in the SAML template isn't correct but several things could be going on. A valuable tool to help debug this is the SAML tracer extension to Firefox.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/saml-tracer/

Answer (score 0):

It was becuase of the redirect url not set properly in the IDP and the port number issues on my server.

If you are interested in the detailed set up please checkout https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEtNUAM79K8